# Ping IPs in a File

Tags: bash, ping

I have file contains below data, i am using script to parse and do ping and show output, i am getting some problem with the script, please assist.

File.txt contains below data:

```
Server          ProdTerminalA   192.168.132.10
Server          ProdTerminalB   192.168.132.11
Server          ProdTerminalC   192.168.132.12
Server          ProdTerminalD   192.168.132.13
Server          DevTerminalA    192.168.131.10
Server          DevTerminalB    192.168.131.11
Server          DevTerminalC    192.168.131.12
Server          DevTerminalD    192.168.131.13
Server          TestTerminalA   192.168.133.10
Server          TestTerminalB   192.168.133.11 
Server          TestTerminalC   192.168.133.12
Server          TestTerminalD   192.168.133.13
```

I am parsing DevTerminal and ping IP from parsing data but not getting expected output.

```
grep "Dev" file.txt | while read ip; do ping -c2 $ip > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo -en "\t Pinging\n"  || echo -en "\t NotPinging\n"; done
```

Expected result should show:

```
DevTerminalA    192.168.131.10  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)
DevTerminalB    192.168.131.11  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)
DevTerminalC    192.168.131.12  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)
DevTerminalD    192.168.131.13  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)
```

Comment: `not getting expected output` ... what output are you getting? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Hi Jsotola, i get below output                                                                                          
 NotPinging
         NotPinging
         NotPinging
         NotPinging
Not sure which column this script is pinging but in actual these are Pinging, also i am looking for output as below..                                                                                            DevTerminalA    192.168.131.10  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)
DevTerminalB    192.168.131.11  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)
DevTerminalC    192.168.131.12  Status (Pinging or NotPinging)

Comment: Looks more like a job for `nmap`.

Comment: ... or `fping`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

grep "Dev" file.txt | while read data; do
   ip=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$data")
   name=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$data")
   echo -en "$name\t$ip"
   ping -c2 $ip > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo -en "\t Pinging\n"  || echo -en "\t NotPinging\n"; 
done
```

Instead of printing `Status` I print the value `Pinging` or `NotPinging`. If you want to print the `Status` before you should use this in the line `echo -en "$name\t$ip"`:

```
echo -en "$name\t$ip\tStatus"
```

Your main problem was the `$ip` variable because this did not contain only the ip, it also contained something like this:

```
Server          DevTerminalA    192.168.131.10
```

So you were using: `ping Server  DevTerminalA  192.168.131.10`

With `awk` I got the **DevTerminalA** (`$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$data")`) and **192.168.131.10** (`$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$data")`).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `read` to read each blank-delimited field into its own variable:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read -r class name addr; do
        if [[ $name != Dev* ]]; then
                continue
        fi

        if ping -c 2 "$addr" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                status=Pinging
        else
                status=NotPinging
        fi

        printf '%s\t%s\tStatus %s\n' "$name" "$addr" "$status"
done
```

This script reads the list from its standard input stream. You may tweak the output formatting any way you want.

Testing on my LAN:

```bash
$ ./script <File.txt
DevTerminalA  192.168.131.10  Status NotPinging
DevTerminalB  192.168.131.11  Status NotPinging
DevTerminalC  192.168.131.12  Status NotPinging
DevTerminalD  192.168.131.13  Status NotPinging
```

The same thing, but using `awk` instead:

```c
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }

$2 ~ /^Dev/ {
        if (!system("ping -c 2 " $3 ">/dev/null 2>&1"))
                status="Pinging"
        else
                status="NotPinging"

        print $2, $3, "Status " status
}
```

Note that this technically contains a code injection vulnerability in that the string in the third field may be crafted to execute arbitrary code (by simply including a `;` and a further shell command).

Testing:

```bash
$ awk -f script File.txt
DevTerminalA  192.168.131.10  Status NotPinging
DevTerminalB  192.168.131.11  Status NotPinging
DevTerminalC  192.168.131.12  Status NotPinging
DevTerminalD  192.168.131.13  Status NotPinging
```